# Show that any infinite set $X$ may be endowed by a metric d such that $X$ has a limit point in $(X,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is an exercise I've been dealing with for a few days; I was wondering if anyone could help me with a hint or just telling me the answer. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Our set $X$  has a subset that can be mapped in a one to one way to the rationals.